# Add text before img src

Tags: jquery, text, image, addition, src

I tried to add a text before a image. That image haven't an default class/id.
The code is like this:

```
$('.status img').attr('src', 'LINK IMAGE').after('My text');
```

Edit:
Complete code:

```
$('.status img').attr('src', 'LINK IMAGE1').after('My text1');
$('.status img').attr('src', 'LINK IMAGE2').after('My text2');
$('.status img').attr('src', 'LINK IMAGE3').after('My text3');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="status">T1<img /></li>
<li class="status">T2<img /></li>
<li class="status">T3<img /></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
var imgArray = new Array('http://cache2.allpostersimages.com/p/LRG/20/2070/7T92D00Z/posters/bitte-im-sitzen-pinkeln.jpg', 'http://cache2.allpostersimages.com/p/LRG/20/2070/7T92D00Z/posters/bitte-im-sitzen-pinkeln.jpg', 'http://cache2.allpostersimages.com/p/LRG/20/2070/7T92D00Z/posters/bitte-im-sitzen-pinkeln.jpg');
var count = 1;

$('.status').children('img').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('src', imgArray[count]);

});
```